JsonIgnore only when output API, not when caching
So I am developing an API which uses a redis cache in C#. I am using dotnet 8, so I am using the build in system.text.json for serializing and deserializing.
For redis I also cache the data by serializing it to json. But now I have the problem that for the caching I need to ignore less properties then for the output off the API. What is the best way to make this possible? Because when I put [JsonIgnore] on the property it ignores it for both.

Why not just create a DTO for the API response, as you would normally do anyways to prevent over-posting or accidentally leaking sensitive information. Then you don't need to ignore anything in the API reponse, since the DTO will only contain what is necessary.

Technically there are at least two ways to achieve the desired result:

hard - by implementing a custom JSON ignore attribute in combination with custom ASP.NET JSON formatter
conditional serialization in combination with a custom JSON ignore attribute

If you have 10-100 objects than I would listen to an advise of Mushroomator and simply use a separate DTO for your API responses.

Yea it is around 50 objects, but the important part is performance so is creating lots of new DTO objects not slower?

@kevingoos Conditional serialization or custom formatter will be slower for sure. Both of them have to execute an additional piece of code before actual serialization happens. But any of the available options will deliver acceptable performance unless you have very specific requirements to optimize every millisecond and byte (otherwise why are you using a standard JSON serializer?). IMHO, your main goal is to make your code easy to understand and maintain.

One point to mention about "lots of new DTO objects": technically it can be a lot slower if you allocate really large chunks of memory, execute complex logic during copying and/or those millions of objects are somehow promoted to GC Gen 2 where they immediately die. In this case a runtime has to wait for memory allocation, execute complex CPU bound operations, often clean Gen 2 and do a few other nasty things. But if you are creating a hundred new DTOs, serialize them and kill immediately in Gen 0, then this overhead is virtually unnoticeable.
